# ktor - make a post request with different naming of the keys of the JSON in kotlin and django

Tags: django, kotlin, request, http-post, ktor

I want to make a post request with different naming of the JSON keys in Ktor and django. It is not a big deal but I want to follow the convention of naming the vals in Kotlin and django.

This is how my user post request body looks in Kotlin/Ktor:

```
    @Serializable
data class UserPostRequest(
    val username: String,
    val email: String,
    val password: String,
    val password_check: String
)
```

The problem with this on is the "password_check" val, which is not named by convention

> Property name 'password_check' should not contain underscores

When I try to change it to passwordCheck, make post request, it returns me an error that the passwords do not match.

I assumed this is because django expects 'password_check' as a JSON key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SerialName](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/-serial-name/) annotation to override the name of the key:

```
@Serializable
data class UserPostRequest(
    val username: String,
    val email: String,
    val password: String,
    @SerialName("password_check")
    val passwordCheck: String
)
```

Comment: yep, i think this will do. Thank you !